# How can I write $\sum\limits_{p \leq q \text{ prime}}\log (p-1)$ using Chebyshev's function(s)?

Tags: summation, prime-numbers, logarithms, chebyshev-function

> **Question:** If $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers how do I write $\sum\limits_{p \leq q \text{ prime}}\log (p-1)$ using Chebyshev's function(s) ?

I would like to think  $\sum\limits_{p \leq q \text{ prime}}\log (p-1)=\vartheta(q-1)$ but disturbingly I lack faith in that thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which is correct (the lack of faith I mean), because
$$\sum\limits_{p \leq q \text{ & prime}}\log{(p-1)}=
\sum\limits_{p \leq q \text{ & prime}} \left(\log{p}+\log{\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)}\right)=\\
\sum\limits_{p \leq q-1 \text{& prime}} \log{p}+\log{q}+\sum\limits_{p \leq q \text{ & prime}}\log{\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)}=\\
\vartheta(q-1)+\log{q}+\sum\limits_{p \leq q \text{ & prime}}\log{\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)}=\\
\vartheta(q-1)+\log{\left(q\cdot\prod\limits_{p \leq q \text{ & prime}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\right)}=\\
\vartheta(q-1)+\log{\left(\frac{q}{\log{q}}\cdot \log{q}\prod\limits_{p \leq q \text{ & prime}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\right)} = ...$$

which, according to [Mertens' third theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems#In_number_theory)

$$... = \vartheta(q-1)+\log{\left(\frac{q}{\log{q}}\right)} + \log{\left( \log{q}\prod\limits_{p \leq q \text{ & prime}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\right)} \sim \\
\vartheta(q-1)+\log{\left(\frac{q}{\log{q}}\right)} -\gamma$$
for large prime $q$'s.

Comment: I think it is fair to ask about $\sum_{p \leq q \text{ prime}}\log(q-k)$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}.$ I am not able to see that result form Merten. But perhaps I am missing it. Should I ask that as a separate question ?

Comment: Indeed, that case won't be easy to tackle, but you never know. Yes, in a separate question (you can link it with this one), hopefully someone will answer it.

Comment: @rytebase  - If $\pi(q)$ is the prime counting function can I write for large $n$ $$\sum\limits_{p \leq q \text{  prime}}\log{(p-1)} \sim \vartheta(q-1) +\log \pi(q)-\gamma $$ ?

Comment: @AntonioHernandezMaquivar for large $q$, yes, due to [PNT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem).