# How do I write $\sum\limits_{p \leq q \text{ prime}}\log (p-x)$ using Chebyshev's function(s)?

Tags: summation, logarithms, chebyshev-function

> **Question:** If $x\in \mathbb{N}$ and $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers how do I write $\sum\limits_{p \leq q \text{ prime}}\log (p-x)$ using Chebyshev's function(s) ?

---

I have some partial results: The case $x=0$ is answered explicitly by definition of the Chebyshev function. The case $x=1$ can be solved "explicitly" and approximately via Merten's third theorem[$^1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems#In_number_theory). (See a related problem and answer[$^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2939428/how-can-i-write-sum-limits-p-leq-q-text-prime-log-p-1-using-chebyshev)). In particular for $q$ large

$$ \sum\limits_{p \leq q \text{ prime}}\log{(p-1)}\sim\vartheta(q-1)+\log{\left(\frac{q}{\log{q}}\right)} -\gamma$$ ; where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant[$^3$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant). I think it is also fair to ask if there are functions other than Chebyshev that are better suited for this calculation.